# Why are the std::atomic_{char,schar,etc.} typedefs allowed to be typedefs to a base class of std::atomic<T>, and not to atomic<T> only?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, atomic, std

C++11 [atomics.types.generic]p7:

> There shall be named types corresponding to the integral specializations of `atomic`, as specified in Table 145, and a named type `atomic_bool` corresponding to the specified `atomic<bool>`. Each named type is a either typedef to the corresponding specialization **or a base class of the corresponding specialization**. If it is a base class, it shall support the same member functions as the corresponding specialization.

(emphasis added)

What's the rationale for letting `std::atomic_char` not be identical to `std::atomic<char>`, and so on for all the other types?  What flexibility does this enable, and why is it useful?  At first glance I don't understand why these wouldn't be required to be typedefs to `std::atomic<T>` specializations directly.

Note that [N2427](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html) which proposed `<atomic>` says that the typedefs are to specializations exactly, and not possibly to base classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably there because someone already had an implementation of atomics using `std::atomic_*` types as base classes and complained enough/provided a good argument towards this approach.

In [MSVC](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/720151/c-11-unsupported-std-atomic-bool-constructor) such an implementation is suggested.

In [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3193.htm) it is stated that

> Remove the definional base-class relationship between atomic_.... named types and the corresponding specializations of the atomic template class. The base-class relationship is now implementation-dependent. This change ensures compatibility with C. Some member functions and operators, that were formerly inherited from the base class, must be hoisted from the named types to the specializations.

Comment: The C compatibility argument looks like the winner here.  Sad, somewhat, but understandable.  (But it's not like this should matter hugely for much code, as it's mostly observable only with things like `std::is_same` and sometimes in overloading and template argument deduction contexts.  So it's not too big a deal.)